# Add an Action Column in Dynamically generated DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am generating a DataGrid control dynamically with this code :

```
//c# code
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
dg.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
getData gd = new getData();
UserData[] userData = gd.getUserRecord();
dg.ItemsSource = userData;

panel1.Children.Add(dg);

//XAML code
<StackPanel Name="panel1"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="18.971,24,24,0" Grid.Column="1">
```

Now, I want to add an additional column named 'Action' to this data-grid and on each row, it should have a delete & edit button. I searched through the internet but got only result for generating only an action column dynamically whereas I need all the control to generate dynamically.

PS: `UserData` is my custom getter/setter class and `getData` have methods to get data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplate`:

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
dg.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
getData gd = new getData();
UserData[] userData = gd.getUserRecord();
dg.ItemsSource = userData;

FrameworkElementFactory sp = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
sp.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
FrameworkElementFactory delete = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
delete.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("deleted click!"); }));
delete.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, "Delete");
FrameworkElementFactory edit = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Button));
edit.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("edited click!"); }));
edit.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, "Edit");
edit.SetValue(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0));
sp.AppendChild(delete);
sp.AppendChild(edit);

DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
{
    Header = "new...",
    CellTemplate = new DataTemplate { VisualTree = sp }
};

dg.Columns.Add(dataGridTemplateColumn);
```